# Class with template parameter

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-umlcd

AFAIK pgf-umlcd does not support classes with template parameter (`std::vector<T>` for instance).

Does anybody have a workaround allowing the drawing of such classe?
Is there a simple PGF/Tikz trick to do so?

I would achieve something roughly equivalent to MetaUML rendering.
See [MetaUML documentation](http://netcologne.dl.sourceforge.net/project/metauml/metauml_manual/0.2.5/metauml_manual_0.2.5.pdf) page 8/9, section 2.5 "Parametrized Classes (Templates)".

Thanks!

Comment: I have edited the question to take your comment into account: I would like something close to MetaUML template classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a new style `template parameter` that adds a dashed box to the upper right corner of the diagram:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}
\tikzset{
    template parameter/.style={
        append after command={
            node [draw, densely dashed, umlcolor, font=\ttfamily]
                at (\tikzlastnode.north east)
                {#1}
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{interface}[template parameter=std::vector<T>,text width=7cm]{TestInterface}{0,0}
            \operation{Test}
        \end{interface}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is almost what I want. Is there a way to replace `std::vector<T>` by the content of the parameter automatically?

Comment: @ThomasMoulard: Yes, sorry, I had accidentally left a static value in the code. The edited version of my answer uses the parameter value.